# Chrome auto re-submits HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I have an angular 1.x application that is doing an HTTP POST to an api. If the api takes longer than 3-5 seconds to process the request, Chrome is submitting a second request before the first is finished, causing the api to attempt to process the same request twice.

Looking at the chrome dev tools, it only shows one request but wireshark clearly shows 2 HTTP POST requests to the same endpoint.

I've so far been unable to find documentation on this behavior.

Has anyone else ran into this or found any information about how to control it?

**EDIT to add code sample**

HTML with ng-click

```
<span><i class="fa fa-refresh" ng-click="reSubmit(transaction.transId)"></i></span>
```

angular controller function

```
$scope.reSubmit = function(transId) {
        RemediationService.reSubmit(transId).then(function(data) {
            init();
        });
    };
```

Angular service function

```
self.reSubmit = function(id) {
        return $http.post(API + '/remediation/reSubmit/', {
            transId: id
        });
    };
```

Currently using a test handler server side using HapiJS in Node to cause the issue by forcing a 10 second delay.

```
reSubmit = async function(request, reply) {
    console.log('test');
    setTimeout(function(){
        reply({message:"success"})
    }, 10000)
}
```

After all of the above code is executed, here is what we see:

1. Chrome network tab in dev tools shows 2 requests, and HTTP OPTIONS request that was successful with HTTP 200 and a single HTTP POST with the expected payload containing the transaction ID
2. Console log "test" twice
3. Wireshark shows the HTTP OPTIONS, and 2 HTTP POST requests.
4. After the 10 seconds is up, the single HTTP POST request in chrome shows as successful with the success message.

**EDIT 2 - CORS handling**

This is what we have in place currently to handle CORS and the OPTIONS preflight request:

```
server.route({
        method: 'OPTIONS',
        path: '/{p*}',
        config: {
            handler: function(request, reply) {
                var response = reply();
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Content-Type, Authorization';
                response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
                return response;
            },
            cors: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: If its cross-domain you would see that, the first is a CORS OPTIONS preflight request. iirc these are hidden in Chrome but would be visible in Wireshark.

Comment: The options is visible in chrome AND in wireshark, and those are accounted for. I'm seeing multiple actual POST requests, with data, content type, http method all set accordingly.

The options request is being responded to immediately as http 200, then the http post occurs, which takes 5+ seconds, followed by another http post with the same payload.

Comment: try increasing timeout ?

Comment: Do you control the API? If you do and it's on a different domain, this problem is indicative of two posts and an options due to pre-flight check requests. You would need to end pre-flight check requests from the API to stop this problem.

Comment: @ThisClark I do control the API, but as mentioned previously, the options request is firing off and it's working. I'm getting 1 OPTIONS request and 2 POST requests. The 2nd POST is received after the OPTIONS and after the 1st POST has taken more than 5 or so seconds.

Comment: @ThisClark  Are you suggesting that CORS is causing the 2nd actual POST in addition to the OPTIONS request?

Comment: Yes. I do believe that is the case when your browser is Chrome. It's an optimization technique. I've read about and had to solve this problem before. I'll throw a snippet of code in and answer for you to consider, then later when I have some time I'll try to find the related info that once helped me.

Comment: What version of Node are you using at your server? Check out this QA. If it's 8.0 maybe it's the same bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555414/chrome-firefox-sending-two-posts-under-the-hood-exactly-5-seconds-apart-with-onl

Comment: @ThisClark I'm using 8.0.0 and I will be testing shortly with the latest version to see if the behavior persists, and will report back, thanks!

Comment: That's it! I hadn't thought to see if it was an error in Node's HTTP handling itself. Thanks for the link! Do you want to copy that into an answer and I'll accept it?